# How to remove 'app is using camera' notification in one plus device after vonage opentok tokbox video call is disconnected or completed?

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox, videocall

I have integrated vonage opentok tokbox video call functionality in to my app using this sdk code https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/main/Basic-Video-Chat  . I have also used session.disconnect() method to disconnect call but still this notification remains in notification panel of one plus device.

Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Please help me if anyone have already resolved this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mPublisher?.capturer?.stopCapture()`
Using this line your capturing will be stopped and also that camera notification will be removed.